# Equation for this linear function

Tags: functions

How could I write this function down as an equation?
[image: function]

Function is drawn with red color, where **k1** and **k2** are coefficients which represent the "stepness" of the curve (y=kx+n). This function is purely linear, the values of Y are 0 untill the function hits X1. Then value of Y starts increasing linearly untill a maximum value of Y0 at X0 is reached. After this the function starts to decrease linearly, untill it hits X2. The values of Y are 0 after this point to infinity.

I tried with using two seperate functions one for increasing the one for decreasing and then adding them together. But I just dont get the right result.

Best regards!

Comment: Is it only possible to express it as a piece-wise function? I could do it this way, but am curious if there is one equation to describe it.

Comment: We often get complaints about piecewise definitions.  I don't understand them.  You can do $\max (0, \min (k1(x-x1),k2(x2-x)))$ but is that better?  You can also do it with absolute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rising part is $y=k1(x-x1)$.  The falling one is $y=k2(x2-x)$